# Filter on nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am trying to filter categories, I want the children of Product Category 1.1, but atm i'm getting the children of cartons. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

```
let categories =         [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel1": "1",
    "productCategoryLevel1Description": "Cartons",
    "sortingKeyLevel1": 1,
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 1.1",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "1",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.1.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.1.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.1",
    "categoryCount": 3
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.1.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.1.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.1",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.1.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.1.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.1",
    "categoryCount": 2
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.1.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.1.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.1",
    "categoryCount": 2
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 1.2",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "1",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.2.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.2.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.2",
    "categoryCount": 2
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.2.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.2.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.2",
    "categoryCount": 0
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.2.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.2.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.2",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.2.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.2.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.2",
    "categoryCount": 3
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 1.3",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "1",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.3.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.3.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.3",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.3.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.3.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.3",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.3.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.3.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.3",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.3.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.3.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.3",
    "categoryCount": 0
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 1.4",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "1",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.4.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.4.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.4",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.4.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.4.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.4",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.4.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.4.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.4",
    "categoryCount": 0
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.4.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.4.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.4",
    "categoryCount": 0
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.5",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 1.5",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "1",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.5.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.5.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.5",
    "categoryCount": 4
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.5.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.5.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.5",
    "categoryCount": 0
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.5.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.5.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.5",
    "categoryCount": 3
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.5.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.5.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.5",
    "categoryCount": 0
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.6",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 1.6",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "1",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.6.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.6.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.6",
    "categoryCount": 0
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.6.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.6.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.6",
    "categoryCount": 2
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.6.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.6.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.6",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.6.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.6.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.6",
    "categoryCount": 4
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.7",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 1.7",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "1",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.7.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.7.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.7",
    "categoryCount": 3
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.7.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.7.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.7",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.7.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.7.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.7",
    "categoryCount": 2
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.7.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.7.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.7",
    "categoryCount": 2
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.8",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 1.8",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "1",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.8.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.8.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.8",
    "categoryCount": 0
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.8.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.8.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.8",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.8.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.8.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.8",
    "categoryCount": 0
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "1.8.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 1.8.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "1.8",
    "categoryCount": 2
    }
    ]
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel1": "2",
    "productCategoryLevel1Description": "Films",
    "sortingKeyLevel1": 2,
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 2.1",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "2",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.1.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.1.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.1",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.1.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.1.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.1",
    "categoryCount": 5
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.1.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.1.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.1",
    "categoryCount": 2
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.1.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.1.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.1",
    "categoryCount": 0
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 2.2",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "2",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.2.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.2.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.2",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.2.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.2.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.2",
    "categoryCount": 3
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.2.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.2.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.2",
    "categoryCount": 2
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.2.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.2.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.2",
    "categoryCount": 2
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 2.3",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "2",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.3.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.3.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.3",
    "categoryCount": 4
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.3.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.3.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.3",
    "categoryCount": 2
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.3.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.3.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.3",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.3.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.3.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.3",
    "categoryCount": 2
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 2.4",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "2",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.4.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.4.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.4",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.4.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.4.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.4",
    "categoryCount": 0
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.4.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.4.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.4",
    "categoryCount": 2
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.4.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.4.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.4",
    "categoryCount": 1
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.5",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 2.5",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "2",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.5.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.5.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.5",
    "categoryCount": 4
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.5.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.5.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.5",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.5.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.5.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.5",
    "categoryCount": 0
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.5.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.5.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.5",
    "categoryCount": 0
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.6",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 2.6",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "2",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.6.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.6.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.6",
    "categoryCount": 0
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.6.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.6.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.6",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.6.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.6.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.6",
    "categoryCount": 3
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.6.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.6.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.6",
    "categoryCount": 2
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.7",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 2.7",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "2",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.7.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.7.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.7",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.7.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.7.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.7",
    "categoryCount": 2
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.7.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.7.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.7",
    "categoryCount": 0
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.7.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.7.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.7",
    "categoryCount": 3
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.8",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 2.8",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "2",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.8.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.8.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.8",
    "categoryCount": 3
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.8.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.8.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.8",
    "categoryCount": 2
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.8.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.8.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.8",
    "categoryCount": 0
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "2.8.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 2.8.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "2.8",
    "categoryCount": 3
    }
    ]
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel1": "3",
    "productCategoryLevel1Description": "Protection",
    "sortingKeyLevel1": 3,
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 3.1",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "3",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.1.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.1.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.1",
    "categoryCount": 2
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.1.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.1.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.1",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.1.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.1.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.1",
    "categoryCount": 0
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.1.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.1.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.1",
    "categoryCount": 3
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 3.2",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "3",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.2.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.2.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.2",
    "categoryCount": 2
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.2.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.2.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.2",
    "categoryCount": 4
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.2.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.2.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.2",
    "categoryCount": 0
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.2.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.2.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.2",
    "categoryCount": 1
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 3.3",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "3",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.3.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.3.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.3",
    "categoryCount": 3
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.3.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.3.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.3",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.3.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.3.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.3",
    "categoryCount": 3
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.3.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.3.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.3",
    "categoryCount": 1
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 3.4",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "3",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.4.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.4.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.4",
    "categoryCount": 2
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.4.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.4.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.4",
    "categoryCount": 0
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.4.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.4.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.4",
    "categoryCount": 3
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.4.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.4.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.4",
    "categoryCount": 0
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.5",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 3.5",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "3",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.5.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.5.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.5",
    "categoryCount": 0
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.5.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.5.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.5",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.5.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.5.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.5",
    "categoryCount": 3
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.5.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.5.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.5",
    "categoryCount": 2
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.6",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 3.6",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "3",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.6.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.6.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.6",
    "categoryCount": 2
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.6.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.6.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.6",
    "categoryCount": 0
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.6.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.6.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.6",
    "categoryCount": 4
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.6.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.6.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.6",
    "categoryCount": 1
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.7",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 3.7",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "3",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.7.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.7.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.7",
    "categoryCount": 0
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.7.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.7.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.7",
    "categoryCount": 0
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.7.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.7.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.7",
    "categoryCount": 2
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.7.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.7.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.7",
    "categoryCount": 3
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.8",
    "productCategoryLevel2Description": "Product Category 3.8",
    "productCategoryLevel1": "3",
    "children": [
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.8.1",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.8.1",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.8",
    "categoryCount": 3
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.8.2",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.8.2",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.8",
    "categoryCount": 1
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.8.3",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.8.3",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.8",
    "categoryCount": 4
    },
    {
    "productCategoryLevel3": "3.8.4",
    "productCategoryLevel3Description": "Product Category 3.8.4",
    "productCategoryLevel2": "3.8",
    "categoryCount": 1
    }
    ]
    }
    ]
    }
    ]
```

This is the code that i'm using . I'm using categories.then because in the real code, categories is a promise but that shouldn't make a difference

```
categories.then(h => {
        let filteredCategory = h.filter(x => x.productCategoryLevel1Description == "Cartons").filter(y => y.children.some(z => z.productCategoryLevel2Description == "Product Category 1.1"))
        console.log(filteredCategory)
    })
```

Comment: Please, take some time to read about [mcve] and then [edit] your question to fulfill what is sain in the link

Comment: Filtering on `x.productCategoryLevel1Description == "Cartons"` would seem to explain why you're getting children of cartons.

Comment: @danh But how can I go one deeper ?  there is more code to the right

Comment: you could remove redundant informations, like parent, level dorm the data and take properties who are the same for each level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store the level for addressing the right property.

If you need the level information, you could add a property with the level value. The use of changing keys creates a lot of overhead, because the property name is either unknown or needs an additional variable.

```js
function findChildren(array, category, level = 1) {
    var temp;
    array.some(o => {
        if (o['productCategoryLevel' + level] === category) return temp = o.children;
        return temp = findChildren(o.children || [], category, level + 1);
    });
    return temp;
}

let categories = [{ productCategoryLevel1: "1", productCategoryLevel1Description: "Cartons", sortingKeyLevel1: 1, children: [{ productCategoryLevel2: "1.1", productCategoryLevel2Description: "Product Category 1.1", children: [{ productCategoryLevel3: "1.1.1", productCategoryLevel3Description: "Product Category 1.1.1", categoryCount: 3 }, { productCategoryLevel3: "1.1.2", productCategoryLevel3Description: "Product Category 1.1.2", categoryCount: 1 }, { productCategoryLevel3: "1.1.3", productCategoryLevel3Description: "Product Category 1.1.3", categoryCount: 2 }, { productCategoryLevel3: "1.1.4", productCategoryLevel3Description: "Product Category 1.1.4", categoryCount: 2 }] }, { productCategoryLevel2: "1.2", productCategoryLevel2Description: "Product Category 1.2", children: [{ productCategoryLevel3: "1.2.1", productCategoryLevel3Description: "Product Category 1.2.1", categoryCount: 2 }, { productCategoryLevel3: "1.2.2", productCategoryLevel3Description: "Product Category 1.2.2", categoryCount: 0 }, { productCategoryLevel3: "1.2.3", productCategoryLevel3Description: "Product Category 1.2.3", categoryCount: 1 }, { productCategoryLevel3: "1.2.4", productCategoryLevel3Description: "Product Category 1.2.4", categoryCount: 3 }] }] }];

console.log(findChildren(categories, '1.1'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Objects (and recursion) to the rescue....

```js
class Category {
  constructor(level, description) {
    this.level = level
    this.description = description
    this.children = []
  }
  addChildren(categories) {
    this.children = this.children.concat(categories)
  }
  hasDescendantWithDescription(string) {
    if (this.description === string) return true
    return this.children.some(child => child.hasDescendantWithDescription(string))
  }
}

// exercise left for the reader:
// build a better constructor, and map the input into Category objects
// for now, in code....
const parentA = new Category(1, "TopLevelA")
const parentB = new Category(1, "TopLevelB")
const categories = [parentA, parentB]

parentA.addChildren([
  new Category(2, "A Child A"),
  new Category(2, "A Child B")
])

parentB.addChildren([
  new Category(2, "B Child A"),
  new Category(2, "B Child B")
])

// punch line is here:
console.log(categories.filter(cat => cat.hasDescendantWithDescription('B Child B')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem stems from naming.

Rather than naming things x, y, and z - give them names that actually describe what they are. Once you do that, the Tao will become clear and your problem will solve itself.

See [this article](https://www.joshwulf.com/blog/2020/02/just-say-no-to-loops-and-variables/).

I put your code into a snippet to fix it, but the lack of comprehensible names make the intent unclear. If you are clear what you are doing, make the names clear so others can also do it.

If you can't do that, you are not clear what you are doing, and that is the problem.

The program's logic is unclear because you went into the realm of the unnamed. `x` is an unknown. Solve for `x`.

The rest will follow.

Comment: :-) another chapter for your good article could be titled:  "When writing business logic, transform data into objects and give your objects methods and give your methods good names"

Comment: What, you mean... model the domain in the code?? Revolutionary! :-D